# non-native scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a library that can help to make a scrolling bar, which scrolls for a div in HTML?
Let's say there's a div that's 200 X 200, but everything inside this div is actually 200 * 1000, so you have to scroll down to see everything.

Comment: just add to CSS `overflow` property?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question was about non-native scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), which is based on JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
overflow: auto;
```

for automatic scrollbar insertion, and

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to make it appears.

<sup>**You tagged CSS.*</sup>

### ADDED

You can use CSS3 to style your scrollbars: (Even Google is using them, just take a look in the console.)

- http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/
- http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

Note: IE does not support CSS3 (as always), so you'll have to use the good old IE-specific way to style them.

Currently Webkit browsers will support it: (like Chrome and Safari)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: gray;
}
```

[**TEST IT OUT HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Wwqhb/).

However, this won't work in Firefox, **because they *think* users hate those fancy scrollbars.** So if you really really want to change it, you might try [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), which is a jQuery plugin and is easy to use. IMO, CSS is way better than a plugin, since it contains fewer characters to download.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i said non-native scrolling, and that's native.

Comment: @Andy - Why would you want a non-native scrollbar?

Comment: because native scrollbars are ugly

Comment: @Andy - You know you can modified them with CSS, right? (not talking about IE)

Comment: on the contrary, using css to style scrollbar only works on ie. i am all ears, if you help me get rid of the arrows, make the track gray, make the bar black, and get rid of the unscrollable scrollbar(it's there even when you don't need it).

Comment: @Andy, what are you talking about? CSS3 scroll bar styling *does not* work on IE. Try it out [here](http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to place the scrolling bar on the following div:
    `<div class="myscrolling" >blah blah...</div>`

The CSS:

```
div.myscrolling{
height:200px;
width:200px;
overflow:auto;
}
```